# Calculating Days on every session login

Tags: php, sql

```
<?php

session_start();
@mysql_connect('localhost','','') or die('Please Check Username or Password');
@mysql_select_db('') or die('error connetcing database');

$qry="SELECT DATEDIFF(DueDate, CURDATE()) AS XYZ,ID FROM fresh_orders";

echo $qry;

$rs=mysql_query($qry);
$qry1="";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
    echo $row[0];
    echo $row[1];

    $qry1="update fresh_orders set DDays='".$row[0]."' where ID=".$row[1]."";
    mysql_query($qry1);
}


?>
```

This formula is not working for me.

I want to calculate the difference between payment Due Date and Current Date and update the remaining amount of days in DDays (Due Days) on every session login on individual user's login from Admin(my) side.

Each client have different credit days so need it to affect properly on each id together. Is there any way I can calculate the difference of each ID in one time login?

Answer (score 0):

update fresh_orders set DDays=DATEDIFF(DueDate, CURDATE())

Comment: Did not work for me. Have you got any other option to try